# How good is NVCC at code optimizations?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

How well does NVCC optimize device code? Does it do any sort of optimizations like constant folding and common subexpression elimination?

E.g, will it reduce the following:

```
float a = 1 / sqrtf(2 * M_PI);
float b = c / sqrtf(2 * M_PI);
```

to this:

```
float sqrt_2pi = sqrtf(2 * M_PI); // Compile time constant
float a = 1 / sqrt_2pi;
float b = c / sqrt_2pi;
```

What about more clever optimizations, involving knowing semantics of math functions:

```
float a = 1 / sqrtf(c * M_PI);
float b = c / sqrtf(M_PI);
```

to this:

```
float sqrt_pi = sqrtf(M_PI); // Compile time constant
float a = 1 / (sqrt_pi * sqrtf(c));
float b = c / sqrt_pi;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is way ahead of you. In your example:

```
float a = 1 / sqrtf(2 * M_PI);
float b = c / sqrtf(2 * M_PI);
```

nvopencc (Open64) will emit this:

```
    mov.f32         %f2, 0f40206c99;        // 2.50663
    div.full.f32    %f3, %f1, %f2;
    mov.f32         %f4, 0f3ecc422a;        // 0.398942
```

which is equivalent to

```
float b = c / 2.50663f;
float a = 0.398942f;
```

---

The second case gets compiled to this:

```
float a = 1 / sqrtf(c * 3.14159f); // 0f40490fdb
float b = c / 1.77245f; // 0f3fe2dfc5
```

I am guessing the expression for `a` generated by the compiler should be more accurate than your "optmized" version, but about the same speed.

Comment: So, it *does* constant folding then? And what compiler is nvOpen64? Is it NVidia's or an OSS version? What about the second case?

Comment: nvOpen64 is the NVIDIA compiler, based on [Open64](http://www.open64.net/) (note nvcc isn't a compiler),

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what exactly is nvcc if it's not a compiler?

Comment: To quote the first page of the nvcc documentation: "The CUDA Compiler Driver NVCC". It is a program that steers compilation, but it uses the host C++ compiler, cudafe and cudafe++ (preprocessors), nvOpen64 and ptxas to actually preprocess, compile and assemble code for the GPU.

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear. To be fair, I did not have any faith in a compiler written by NVidia, and it turns out it wasn't written by NVidia at all!

Comment: I think that last comment is a but unfair - nvidia (and ATI/AMD) have been shipping high performance compilers in their shader language SDKs and drivers for years. And nvopencc uses their own modifications to the Open64/gcc front end with their own back end which emits PTX virtual machine assembly code. You can see a paper about their Open64 port [here](http://www.capsl.udel.edu/conferences/open64/2008/).

Comment: Fair enough, I stand corrected then. I can't say I'm well informed about CUDA in general, but I do tend to be sceptical towards special-purpose compilers and VMs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3747/discussion-between-alex-b-and-talonmies)